# php unicode basic zone conversion spreading are

Tags: php, unicode

I met this problem of Arabic UNICODE basic zone some text conversion to UNICODE spreading area code， but not success 。I have the following code， help me see。
This conversion is not correct。 what is the reason

```
<?
header("content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
    mb_http_output( "UTF-8" );
function Un2k($Un){
     $Uk[0] ="چېتيڭپسىقكلشغبنمفگخجروۈزۋداەژۆۇﻻﺋھ";
        $Uk[1] = "ﭺﯥﺕﻱﯓﭖﺱﻯﻕﻙﻝﺵﻍﺏﻥﻡﻑﮒﺥﺝﺭﻭﯛﺯﯞﺩﺍﻩﮊﯙﯗﻻ∥∥";
        $Uk[2] = "ﭼﯦﺗﻳﯕﭘﺳﯨﻗﻛﻟﺷﻏﺑﻧﻣﻓﮔﺧﺟ∥∥∥∥∥∥∥∥∥∥∥∥ﺋﮬ";
        $Uk[3] = "ﭻﯥﺖﻲﯔﭗﺲﻰﻖﻚﻞﺶﻎﺐﻦﻢﻒﮓﺦﺞﺮﻮﯜﺰﯟﺪﺎﻪﮋﯚﯘﻼ∥∥";
        $Uk[4] = "ﭽﯧﺘﻴﯖﭙﺴﯩﻘﻜﻠﺸﻐﺒﻨﻤﻔﮕﺨຠ∥∥∥∥∥∥∥∥∥∥∥∥ﺌﮭ";

        $Un2K1 = "";
        $i ;
        $ix ;
        $s ;
        $s_ ;
        $_s ;
        $L ;
        $_ix ;
        $ix_ ;
        $_TF ;
        $TF_ ;
        $L = mb_strlen($Un,"utf8");

        for ($i=1;$i<$L;$i++){
            $s = mb_substr($Un, $i, 1,"utf8");

            if($i!=$L){ $s_ = mb_substr($Un, $i + 1, 1,"utf8");}else{$s_="";}
            if($i>1){ $_s = mb_substr($Un, $i - 1, 1,"utf8");}else{$_s="";}
            $ix = mb_strpos($Uk[0], $s);
             if(empty($ix)){
                 //
               if($i!=$L){$ix_ = mb_strpos($Uk[0], $s_);}else{$ix_="";}
               if($i>1){$_ix = mb_strpos($Uk[0], $_s);}else{$_ix="";}
               //
                 if($_ix == 0 or mb_strpos("روۈزۋداەژۆۇ", $_s) != 0){
                      $_TF = false;
                 }elseif(mb_substr($Uk[2], $_ix, 1,"utf8") != "." or mb_substr($Uk[4], $_ix, 1,"utf8") != "."){
                     $_TF = true;
                 }
                 if($ix==0){
                    $TF_ = false;
                 }elseif(mb_substr($Uk[3], $ix_, 1,"utf8") != "." or mb_substr($Uk[4], $ix_, 1,"utf8") != "."){
                     $_TF = true;
                 }
                 if(mb_strpos("چېتيڭپسىقكلشغبنمفگخج", $s) != 0){
                     if($_TF == false and $TF_ == false){
                         $Un2K1 = $Un2K1.mb_substr($Uk[1], $ix, 1,"utf8");
                     }elseif($_TF == true and $TF_ == false){
                         $Un2K1 = $Un2K1.mb_substr($Uk[3], $ix, 1,"utf8");
                     }elseif($_TF == false and $TF_ == true){
                         $Un2K1 = $Un2K1.mb_substr($Uk[2], $ix, 1,"utf8");
                     }

                 }elseif(mb_strpos("روۈزۋداەژۆۇ", $s) != 0){
                     if($_TF == false){
                        $Un2K1 = $Un2K1.mb_substr($Uk[1], $ix, 1,"utf8");
                     }elseif($_TF == true){
                        $Un2K1 = $Un2K1.mb_substr($Uk[3], $ix, 1,"utf8");
                     }
                 }else{
                     if($TF_ == false){
                        $Un2K1 = $Un2K1.mb_substr($Uk[4], $ix, 1,"utf8");
                     }elseif($TF_ == true){
                        $Un2K1 = $Un2K1.mb_substr($Uk[2], $ix, 1,"utf8");
                     }
                 }

             }else{
                 $Un2K1 = $Un2K1.$s;
             }
        }
        $Un2K1 = str_ireplace("ﻟﺎ", "ﻻ",$Un2K1);
        $Un2K1 = str_ireplace("(", "<!>",$Un2K1);
        $Un2K1 = str_ireplace(")", "(",$Un2K1);
        $Un2K1 = str_ireplace("<!>", ")",$Un2K1);
        $Un2K1 = str_ireplace("«", "<!>",$Un2K1);
        $Un2K1 = str_ireplace("»", "«",$Un2K1);
        $Un2K1 = str_ireplace("<!>", "»",$Un2K1);
        $Un2K1 = str_ireplace("", "",$Un2K1);
        $Un2K1 = str_ireplace("", "",$Un2K1);
        //$Un2K1 = santatur2($Un2K1);

        return  $Un2K1;
}


function santatur2($str) {  
    $len = mb_strlen($str, 'UTF-8');  
    $string = '';  
    for ($i = $len - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {  
       $string .= mb_substr($str, $i, 1, 'UTF-8');                                                           
    }  
    return $string;  
} 


















?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head>

<body>

<?

echo(Un2k("شاكىر"));


?>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [mb_convert_encoding()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php). It should be quite useful in your case.

Here is an **example** which converts EUC-JP to UTF-7:

```
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, "UTF-7", "EUC-JP");
```

[List of supported encodings](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php)